# Create a buffer on a single LAS file using lidR

Tags: dem, buffer, las, lidr

I want to create a buffer for a single LAS file in order to test different algorithims for DTM creation on a small scale before scaling up to all my files using `LAScatalog`.

I know `LAScatalog` creates a buffer around each LAS file and that you can customize the size of the buffer with `opt_chunk_buffer` but this is for multiple files. I want to do it for just one file.

I can't use `sf` or `terra` as it is still in LAS format and not a raster.

In the [documentation](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/dtm.html) it recommends to use a buffer: `best practice is to always use a buffer to obtain some information about the neighborhood and remove the buffer once the terrain is computed` but does not describe how to do so or to remove the buffer on a individual LAS file. I have searched through all of the questions on here but no one else is asking about a single file.

EDIT 1

I have a 100m wide section of power lines I want to create a DTM and DEM for. When I create a DTM, the points on the north side of are incorrectly interpolated. This is why I need a buffer. When I run `rasterize_terrain` for the DTM I get a warning saying `Warning message: Interpolation of 388 points failed because they are too far from ground points. Nearest neighbour was used but interpolation is weak for those points` . Here is an image of incorrectly interpolated points on the north side.[image]

Comment: If you have a single file how do you want to add a buffer? You must have multiple contiguous files to be able to load a buffer for a given file. Please show a minimal reproducible example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have added a picture and description. I want the buffer to be for this individual file so that the points on the north side of the image shown are correctly interpolated.

Comment: You still did not provide any code or reproducible example. Your dtm is correct, even if not nice. You clipped a concave region, but a triangulation returns a convex object. If you buffer your polygon used to extract the region, you will have the same problem. If you want to hide the ugly part you can simply mask the raster using the original polygon if you have the polygon. But again no reproducible example, I don't know your data. I don't know how you extracted the data.

Comment: I don't think it is a code issue now...I think it is my understanding. The interpolation of the points in the north of the image are not as a result of a lack of a buffer but instead of the algorithm used, as you have so kindly explained so thank you very much! I thought the buffer was used to create pseudo ground points in order to correctly interpolate edge points...which is still correct right? It just wouldn't solve the issue of the untidy area in the north of the image shown...is that right?

Comment: Buffering consists in loading extra points, beyond the spatial area you are working with. This can be done simply by clipping a larger area than what you actually need. The challenge is that those points may be in another file that the main file you are working with. lidR takes can care of that.